# Databrick spark: Scala Get/Set static value in executor

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a databrick job written in Scala. If is it possible to set/get static value within executor.

Following is my code. My driver will assign a value to "valueSetByDriver" variable. My executor able to get the value from "valueSetByDriver" variable.

If my executor assigns a value to "valueSetByExecutor" in the first run, when subsequent executor task runs, it won't be able to get value of "valueSetByExecutor" set by previous run.

```
object mystatic extends Serializable{
    var valueSetByDriver = ""
    var valueSetByExecutor = ""
}
```

Comment: you want to access a member of a class among different executors?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to propagate any data across your cluster then it is always propagated via `Driver -> all executors` and not the opposite. 
Any changes done by executor wont be propagated outside executor's jvm context.